Ошибка в Oracle SQL Developer: PLS-00428: в этом предложении SELECT ожидается фраза INTO
Имеется sql-запрос:
SELECT 
  SUBSTR(t.xmldata, INSTR(t.xmldata,'<TerminalId>')+12, INSTR(t.xmldata,'</TerminalId>')-INSTR(t.xmldata,'<TerminalId>')-12) TerminalId
FROM TERMINALPRESET t;

В случае, если запускать данный запрос в Oracle SQL Developer вручную - результат успешный, формируется табличка с запрашиваемыми данными, но в случае, если создать Job - при его срабатывании в логах имеется следующая ошибка:
"ORA-06550: Строка 1, столбец 757:
PLS-00428: в этом предложении SELECT ожидается фраза INTO
"

Имеется-ли вариант решения данной ситуации?

При использовании select в блоках pl/sql есть ограничения: Все выводимые значения полей должны быть сохранены в переменные(как раз через into). Запрос должен вернуть только одну строку. СТРОГО 1 строку. Если запрос будет возвращать более 1 строки, то нужно использовать циклы и коллекции для сохранения результата. Если запрос вернет 0 строк, получите ошибку NO_DATA_FOUND, ее надо отдельно обрабатывать в блоке EXCEPTION

В oracle можно писать как просто sql запросы вида select * from table, так и pl/sql код. В pl/sql нельзя использовать просто select, потому что данные никуда не вывести, поэтому используется конструкция
select name
into l_name_user
from users;

и дальше уже работать с этой переменной l_name_user
в переменную может записываться только одно значение. Если нам нужно пройти по всем данным из таблицы, тогда в объявлении объявим курсор
Declare
 CURSOR cur IS 
    SELECT id, name, age, address 
    FROM users
    WHERE deleted = 0;
 l_acc_id number;
begin
 --цикл из курсора
 for res in cur
   loop
     begin 
       select au.acc_id
       into l_acc_id
       from acc2users au
       where au.user_id = res.id
       and rownum = 1; --если записей с одним id может быть несколько,костыльное решение, но ошибки не будет
     exception 
       WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
         l_acc_id := NULL;
     end;
 --что то делаем с переменной
   ....
end;



Да. Но если вернется 0 строк или больше 1 будет ошибка. Так же забыли добавить, что переменная, используемая в конструкии into должна быть объявлена и соответствовать типу возвращаемых значений. Т.е. это реальная переменная, а не динамически создаваемая

@ну это основы языка, что в нём нет динамических переменных. А если 0 строк или больше одной, то надо обрабатывать исключения через EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN при 0 строк присваивать null,а если больше одной, то можно использовать костыль с rownumber 1. Смотря что за задача и данные

Лучше добавьте эти ограничения в ответ. Он будет смотреться более солидно. А если с примерами кода, то вообще отлично
